# iphone sqlite static linking?

Tags: iphone, sqlite, static, crash, jailbreak

Anyone out there statically linking sqlite (as opposed to using the dynamic linking)?

I am having issues with users with jailbroken phones not having the same version of sqlite that the stock iPhone assumes (and hence causing crashes).   I'm assuming that staticly linking a known version of sqlite in my app is the answer...

Comment: I thought sqlite was staticly linked on non jail broken iphones, I'm a bit confused...

Comment: Perhaps I'm confused, but the process of adding sqlite to an iPhone app via Xcode involves linking to libsqlite3.0.dylib, which is a dynamic library, right?   On some jailbroken devices, the installed version of sqlite is not the same as the one my app was assuming... I think.   Help anyone?

Answer (score 2):

I needed to have Full Text support (with FTS3 module)

All I did was grab the Sqlite Amalgamation from here:
http://www.sqlite.org/amalgamation.html
and dropped the .h and .c into my project and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Have you found the exact source of the crash? Are you sure it's not a bug in your code that's exposed by the different version of SQLite?

When [I came across a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608608/why-does-cocoa-return-an-empty-string-occasionally) to this I found that it was actually a bug in my code -- I was `sqlite3_reset`ting a prepared statement too early.

Answer (score 1):

You could download the source and create a static library yourself?

Comment: Right... Thanks for prompting me to look again... I thought at first that this would be painful, but the 
"amalgamation" source version was only two headers and a .c file.   Integrated like a charm in Xcode... hopefully I'll soon hear back from beta testers it fixed the jailbroken phone crashes.