# can Jailbroken iphone used for development

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, jailbreak

We have paid developer account for iphone development and we have 2 iphones one jail broken and other one non jail broken. We have registered both phones for development and got provisioning profile. We can use non jailbroken phone for development. But we try to use jail broken phone for development we get message Error starting executable no Provisioned iphone device is connected.

But We can test application on it using ad hoc profile.
Does this means jailbroken devices can not be used for development?
Regards,
Manish

Comment: Please accept one of the answers as "accepted answers" as it helps out the community of Stackoverflow when you do so, and also adds to your own rating.

Comment: If your interested in this question why not support the Area 51 proposal for a [jail-breaking Stack Exchange site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18154/ios-jailbreaking-development?referrer=EuWVi6IpN0_KzzEhC7I-Qw2)

Answer (score 20):

I personally do development/testing on jailbroken devices (I find that it is nice for profiling/debugging with all the UNIX tools available, as well as testing out code for checking for tampered plist files ;-) ) as well as non jailbroken devices.

I have not had any problems specifically with jailbroken devices, as they behave exactly like stock standard firmwares..

Have you:

- Added the UDID to the provisioning profile
- Tried removing and adding the provisioning profile in XCode organizer
- Rebooting the phone then trying to build an app targeting the device

Comment: Thanks I followed the above steps and I am able to use jailbroken device for development.

Comment: In fact jailbroken devices do not always behave exactly like the standard firmware: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/608608/why-does-cocoa-return-an-empty-string-occasionally

Answer (score 5):

I personally am paying the $99 per year and use my iPod Touch 2G (jailbroken) for development purposes. I have seen no disadvantages to using jailbroken devices for development. I have actually seen some advantages to using jailbroken devices.

Answer (score 4):

I have no any problems with development for jailbroken iPhone. Moreover I like to use several advantages... for example full-featured UNIX console environment into device.
In additional using jailbroken iPhone may help developer better understand how iPhone/OS/Environment works at low level.

You may add new **Target** to your project and use it if you connect jailbroken device.

You just need to add two keys for new target in User-Defined Settings (Target->Get Info->"Build" Tab->Show "User-Defined Settings")

```
 PROVISIONING_PROFILE_ALLOWED  NO 
 PROVISIONING_PROFILE_REQUIRED NO
```

So you will have two very similar targets... one for jailbroken and second for povisioned iPhone.

Answer (score 3):

Be warned - the iPhone Developer agreement now bans you from jailbreaking your phones:
http://news.softpedia.com/news/iPhone-Developer-Agreement-Bans-iPhone-OS-Jailbreak-108599.shtml

I'm not sure what you should do if, say, you want your application to disable itself on jailbroken phones - how would you test it?

Comment: it's now legal to jailbreak your iOS device according to US law.

Comment: Legal by DMCA exclusion, but that doesn't get you out of an agreement that you've made with Apple.

Comment: @Darron: I never made any agreements with Apple. I purchased my iPod second-hand and jailbroke it. No agreements broken! :D

Answer (score 3):

Jailbroken devices won't work with push notification. I lost almost one day with one such device. So better stay away from jail broken device for development .

Comment: I've heard people say this before, but I've jailbroken every iPhone I've owned, and I've always had push notifications work (both from my test apps, and from App Store apps on my phone).

Comment: @Nate I haven't received push notification with jail broken devices.