# Can I use a jail broken device for iPhone app development

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, jailbreak

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [can Jailbroken iphone used for development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995262/can-jailbroken-iphone-used-for-development)

For example, testing in app purchase, game centre, icloud or notification.

Anyone have tested and verified if it work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had tried to call server data from the app in Jail Broken device. I am not able to call webservices from it. It always display error. On other had application is working fine in factory unlock device.

Answer (score 1):

It works for the most part. Some things don't work perfectly. Sometimes Game Center won't automatch in Sandbox mode for example. But mostly it works.

Answer (score 1):

I unjailbroken mine yesterday because it got stuck when I run the app. It said something like Locktalking so I restored it to iOS6 beta 3. The most of the 'cool' thinks of jailbreaking have a price (of course, they deserve it, but I don't need them so much) so it wasn't an advantage at all.