# How to deploy an iPhone application from Xcode 4.3.1 to a real iPhone device having IOS 5.0.1 jailbreaked

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, xcode4.3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Install iOS Apps on device without developer program, iOS 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494398/install-ios-apps-on-device-without-developer-program-ios-5-1)

I want to be able to create the project in Xcode and run the app on the simulator too. 
Essentially, I want to develop app *before* having certificate, but targeting App Store in the end. I will get the certificate once I'm done, so I won't waste money should I quit halfway.

Comment: You can run on the simulator with the free developer id, no need to pay. If you are ready to test on the device and deploy to the App Store, you need to pay.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot deploy to a device without a paid developer account.

Comment: I don't think that's strictly true; you could do an Enterprise deployment, but that has nothing to do with the App Store.  http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/Enterprise_Deployment_Guide.pdf

Comment: @RobertHarvey well, that would be a lot more expensive and even harder to get, hence your correctly stated exception is irrelevant for this specific case.

Comment: Still, I do think there's a way to deploy to your own personal device without involving the store.  I don't even think the device needs to be jailbroken.

Comment: Here it is: http://www.intertech.com/Blog/Post/Xcode-4-Deploying-Your-App-to-Your-Own-iPhone-iPad-iPod-touch.aspx, although it does require a paid developer account.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Enterprise deployment requires an Enterprise developer account, which is $299 a year and requires a business with a Dun & Bradstreet number in order to register for. I use Enterprise accounts at work all day long. It is not a matter of the store, it is because an non-jailbroken iOS device will not allow an IPA to be installed that was not signed with a distribution provisioning profile and certificate generated by Apple.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend doing it, but it **is** possible to deploy your application to a device **without** paying for a developer account on a jailbroken phone. This ([can Jailbroken iphone used for development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995262/can-jailbroken-iphone-used-for-development)) question has a lot of info on how you would go about deploying your app. This ([Install iOS Apps on device without developer program, iOS 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494398/install-ios-apps-on-device-without-developer-program-ios-5-1)) question has great step-by-step instructions for what you want to do. Here's a sample of the instructions in the second link:

> 1. Create self-signed certificate with name 'iPhone Developer'
> 2. Turn 'Code Signing Identities' in Xcode project Build Settings back on - to use your self-signed certificate 'iPhone Developer'
> 3. Change info.plist occurrences as stated
> 4. Download ldid, make executable
> 5. Create python script, stick it in /usr/bin, change python script references accordingly
> 6. Change iPhoneCodeSign.xcspec to use ldid3.py
> 7. Create tdmtanf file on device with touch over ssh
> 8. Don't put -gta flags in 'Other Code Signing Flags'

Hope this helps!